# android studio, 2 projects with same installer file icon

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, apk

I'm working on two projects, all two have different icon for .apk installer and app (same file for apk and link), but now, one app show the same .apk icon of the other file.
Eg. app 1 have icon x, app 2 have icon y. After i create new project for the app 2, app 1 icon change in y. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***Solved***] The bug is persistent, but just **rename** the .apk file and it restore the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "Clean project" and "Rebuild project" on "Build" menu.